# Auto fill/copy answer within excel dropdown

Tags: excel, menu, copy, selection, dropdown

I'm wanting to have a an excel spreadsheet automatically fill in a dropdown selection based on a previous dropdown.

Basically i have a spreadsheet that allows me to pick colours of items from basic dropdown lists each row has its own dropdown. Often the colours are the same so would like it to automatically fill in the next rows colour the same as the previous lines for me?

anyone have any ideas? Can't seem to find much on only filling out the dropdown? Also is there a method to fill out all dropdowns simultaniously?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this depending on what you mean by 'drop-down'.

If you are using a 'form control' drop-down then you have the option under right-click>Format Control... to specify a cell whose value will be set when you change the drop-down selection. You can then use this value to affect other areas of your spreadsheet.

If your drop-down is done using the 'Data Validation' then it will only affect the cell you have put it in. In this case you will have to turn to VBA.

For this you would use the Worksheet_Change event and an If statement checking that the Target is the drop-down cell, then you can code the filling in of your other dropdowns. Check out this [microsoft guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel) for triggering VBA from cell changes.